# image in user control doesn't display in the page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

My solution contains two projects, one is class library and the other is windows store app blank page project. There's a user control in my class library project, and in the user control, there's an image, the image's property set as embedded resource. But when I use the user control in my xaml page, the image doesnt' display. Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you set image source 
promogallery?

Comment: Hi @irog, yes, I use the path ms-appx:///... to access the image

Answer (score 1):

Change the Build Type from "Embedded Resource" to "Content"

Comment: Hi @Jim, thanks for your reply, but I want to compile the image to the dll

Comment: ah ok... in WPF you could do something explicit like Source="/ClassLibrary;component/Images/WP_000170.jpg", but I'm not having luck with that in Windows 8 Store apps... still researching.

Comment: looks like you'll have to pull the resource out and assign the property via code using [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Take a look at the [responses here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your image file is not showing up in the solution explorer..

Go to your Solution explorer,

right click and select "Add"

select "existing item" and add your image name..

that should do the trick...